# Did the Quesdb performance change with the implementation of the new geohash type?

Tags: performance, geospatial, questdb

With the new addition of the `geohash` type in update 6.0.5, has the performance improved? Specifically, will this improve performance for weather / geospatial data ingestion relative to previous Questdb iterations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addition of geohashes means that there is a new type for this kind of data. If you are using existing types for weather data, there will be no change in performance. There are internal improvements which make working with the geohash type more efficient than storing these values as strings of symbols, for example.

For more info, see the geohash documentation at https://questdb.io/docs/concept/geohashes/